# Favicon using data:image not working in IE 11

Tags: html, internet-explorer-11, favicon

The following code is not working in IE 11. Any idea?

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABAAAAAQCAYAAAAf8/9hAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAJcEhZcwAADsQAAA7EAZUrDhsAAACMSURBVDhP7ZCxDYAgFESdxXkMo9A5hguwAhUDEFoLFqCxIXEAFzjhy1dj1IaWSwjc5/K40KFSDVAAS5DozUBLhFi8hNrS5TrRDIhQ7shwLusE0GDTEE7DZu8SxM8ngKDZP/TZQASN0UywBWD9gHG9su8NitjTnprwmRvc878AYE4t+LWfP6hRA1QDgB1UmrnthDo3VgAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==">
```

Answer (score 3):

Data URI's are just not supported in IE. This blog from microsoft mentions it,

[Fun with Favicons](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ieinternals/2013/09/07/fun-with-favicons/)

Just another reason why people shout stop using/supporting this old browser.

Answer (score 1):

This is incorrect, data URI is supported in Internet Explorer: https://caniuse.com/#search=data%20uri

I have had trouble with favicons in Internet Explorer but as an img tag they work fine:

```
<img src="<enter data URI here>" alt="image">
```

I used this to convert: https://websemantics.uk/tools/image-to-data-uri-converter/